# Open Save DialogBox Window (Desktop application)

Tags: c#

Is there any DialogBox in window c# (Desktop Application) which has both save and open button?.

Comment: Why do you need such a dialog box? What are your requirements?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such standard dialog box. Whilst you could make one yourself, you should refrain from doing so since it would surely result in very confused users.